# How to reconfigure GIT for imported Laravel project on Windows and deploy to Linux server

Tags: linux, windows, git, laravel

I have a Laravel project copied from different computer and it used Git at that computer.

I run 
'git add' 
and then 
'git commit'
, but I got error:

> fatal: could not parse HEAD'. Then I run 'git fsck' to check. This is a log:
>       'Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
>   Checking objects: 100% (15395/15395), done.
>   error: HEAD: invalid sha1 pointer 8969f7fc321490b0f8d716b4ec46806307047a46
>   error: refs/heads/master: invalid sha1 pointer 8969f7fc321490b0f8d716b4ec46806307047a46
>   error: refs/remotes/origin/HEAD: invalid sha1 pointer 8969f7fc321490b0f8d716b4ec46806307047a46
>   error: refs/remotes/origin/master: invalid sha1 pointer 8969f7fc321490b0f8d716b4ec46806307047a46
>   error: HEAD: invalid reflog entry 8969f7fc321490b0f8d716b4ec46806307047a46
>   error: refs/heads/master: invalid reflog entry 8969f7fc321490b0f8d716b4ec46806307047a46
>   error: refs/remotes/origin/master: invalid reflog entry 8969f7fc321490b0f8d716b4ec46806307047a46
>   dangling blob 670ada327a149925c76a58ca40e45639dea68520
>   dangling blob 180cac293ee826b9db692dd1c33aacc88b9c7e6a
>   dangling blob 183903d3c3e4c6d7d8c42e0e19512f65b4fd2364
>   dangling blob db68ddf31bf9c0b97b2976134d0aab0dc5a7f182
>   dangling blob 88752d671f4f04cfadf764c17bb7fe2958e4d074
>   dangling blob a28c5281ec1d94d711559c9a1e6b301afdfcdad6
>   dangling blob 2eb64b853146373317416b443068604175ffec52
>   dangling blob 4dbf7a53323b624cb7bf6dab5ac256c02e3c9ac5'

I want to add the project to my Git and then deploy to the production server running on Linux Ubuntu. On production server there is also Git, so how to restore the project in my Git and deploy on server without loosing previous commits on Git on server.

Answer (score 0):

You have to `clone` the project on the target production server.

```
git clone git@yourserver
```

Then you have the last state that is included in the repository with the history. Then you can pull the master branch if you want to deploy on your production system.

If your index is broken your can reset the index with the following command:

```
rm .git/index
git reset
```

Comment: I run 'rm .git/index' and then 'git reset'. I have got error: 'fatal: Could not parse object 'HEAD''

Comment: I think you should clone your project again and test it out.

Comment: I tried to clone the project, but I've got these errors:  'error: refs/heads/master does not point to a valid object!
error: refs/remotes/origin/HEAD does not point to a valid object!
error: refs/remotes/origin/master does not point to a valid object!
done.
fatal: update_ref failed for ref 'HEAD': cannot update ref 'HEAD': trying to write ref 'HEAD' with nonexistent object 8969f7fc321490b0f8d716b4ec46806307047a46
Unlink of file 'promarket.kz/.git/objects/pack/pack-82d9890587144e2ccc8f3922dc26531901a39731.idx' failed. Should I try again? (y/n)'